# Administrator Password pop up screen does not open

Tags: macos

I have Macpro4.1 running Yosemite. Suddenly I can't do anything that requires Administrator's password. The pop up screen to type in password does not come up.
If I go to Users & Groups and click on the lock, It will say authenticating but just spins and password screen does not open. If I try to access passwords in Keychain the app will lock up and I have to force quit.
Any ideas on how to fix this problem?

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :)  I hope you come to find this site has a lot to offer! In case you haven't already, it's worth taking the time to read the [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour). All the best with your question!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to:

**Reset NVRAM or PRAM on your Mac**

Shut down your Mac, then turn it on and immediately press and hold these four keys together: **Option, Command, P, and R**. You can release the keys after about 20 seconds, during which your Mac might appear to restart.

[image]

Test after this. 
**Note**: When your Mac finishes starting up, you might want to open System Preferences and adjust any settings that were reset, such as sound volume, display resolution, startup disk selection, or time zone.

If this doesn't help then at last try to: 
**Reset the SMC on Mac**

First, shut down your Mac and Press **Shift-Control-Option** on the left side of the built-in keyboard, then press the **power button** at the same time. Hold these keys and the power button for 10 seconds. Release all keys. And, Press the power button again to turn on your Mac.

This two reset should help.

Comment: **NVRAM** *include sound volume, display resolution, startup-disk selection, time zone, and recent kernel panic information.* **and SMC has** *Responding to presses of the power button,Responding to the display lid opening and closing on Mac notebooks,Battery management,Thermal management,Sudden Motion Sensor(SMS),Ambient light sensing,Keyboard backlighting,Status indicator light (SIL) management,Battery status indicator lights,Selecting an external (instead of internal) video source for some iMac displays* **Seeing password popup being affected by this would be a surprise, but a welcome one**

Comment: @ankiiiiiii
Last year, I had the same issue. Mac started freezing when I press the lock to provide a password. It simply freeze and doesn't open. Reset NVRMA helped me. So I thought to share here too for this solution. I am not sure whether he has tired this or not.